# Why doesn't Nobita use Anywhere Door to reach school on time?

Tags: doraemon

Nobita is always late to school. Why doesn't he simply use Anywhere Door to reach school on time?

Answer (score 2):

There was a moral problem in using the anywhere door for getting quickly to school. Doraemon had come to past to help Nobita when it is strictly required for him. Doraemon's intention was to help him getting better daily for a brighter future by mixing use of Nobita's hard work and his own gadgets. Giving him gadgets so often like anywhere door to go to school daily will only make Nobita heavily relying on Doraemon for almost everything and his life would only become more miserable, let alone improving.

From the [Doraemon Wiki](https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/Doraemon#Nobita_Nobi):

> Nobita and Doraemon are best friends. They both have a strong bond and will never leave each other's side. As seen in many episodes.
>
> Most of the time, whenever Nobita comes home crying and whining about his bad day, Nobita would pounce on and/or wrap his arms around Doraemon begging for something to make him feel better. Nobita once called Doraemon "useless" due to the numerous times where Doraemon almost never helps him get of any tight spot, such as when Nobita is being chased around by Gian and Suneo or unable to get help with his homework. Being called useless was enough to make Doraemon mad at Nobita and feels the right to prove how he isn't useless, by conveniently taking out the gadget Nobita needs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include some supporting evidence, such as direct quotes from the source material.

Comment: It's also worth typing in any text that you wish to be read, as images exclude those who rely on text to speech software, the visually impaired audience. We have a policy of inclusiveness and accessibility on the network.